# Repetición en función número introducido por teclado - Java

Tags: java

Tengo una duda con Java a ver si pueden ayudarme.
Estoy intentando que, al introducir un número por teclado con Scanner, se me repita una pregunta el número de veces que ponga en Scanner.
Me explico:

Me gustaría que al pedir, por ejemplo: ¿Cuántas personas quieres registrar en el programa?
Si introduzco 4, que posteriormente me pregunte: Indica el número que identifica a esa persona y que esto se repita 4 veces, que es el número de personas que quiero registrar.

**Ejemplo:**

-- ¿Cuantas personas quieres registrar en el programa?: 4

- Número identificativo persona: 12
- Número identificativo persona: 5
- Número identificativo persona: 2
- Número identificativo persona: 44

Y que me pida el número identificativo tantas veces como número de personas quiera registrar.
(personas 2, ID 2 / persona 5, ID 5...)

Edito, añadiendo el código que tenía. Cómo era una prueba y no veía como acabarlo, seguro que hay alguna cosa si sentido del todo:

```
    import java.util.*;
    
    public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int codUser = 0;
        boolean valorCorrecto = true;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
       
        System.out.print("¿Cuantas persones quieres registrar?: ");
        valorCorrecto = entrada.hasNextInt();
        
        if (valorCorrecto) {
            codUser = entrada.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < codUser; i++) {
                System.out.print("Identifique su número de registro: ");

                System.out.println("El número es " + codUser);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

El if (valorCorrecto), lo he puesto para verificar que el número que se introduce sea entero.

Espero haberme explicado bien y puedan ayudarme.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Podríais editar la pregunta y añadir en modo texto el código que lleves hasta el momento?

Comment: Ya lo puse. Seguro que hay cosas que pueden carecer de sentido. Estaba intentando estructurarlo de la mejor forma posible para llegar a hacer lo que estoy buscando. Espero que pueda servir de algo. saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitarías hacer uso de un arreglo que almacene temporalmente los datos que vayas ingresando

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Bucle {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Cuantas personas deseas registrar? ");
int cantidad=sc.nextInt();
int numeroIdentificativo=0;
int []arregloDenumeroIdentificativos=new int[cantidad];

for (int i=0;i<cantidad;i++ ) {
    System.out.println("Ingrese numero identificativo de la persona :"+(i+1));
       numeroIdentificativo=sc.nextInt();
       if(numeroIdentificativo>=100||numeroIdentificativo<=0){
           System.out.println("Solo se permiten numeros identificativos entre 0-100");
            System.exit(0);
       }else{
       arregloDenumeroIdentificativos[i]=numeroIdentificativo;
   }
}

System.out.println("");
for (int i=0;i<cantidad;i++ ) {
    System.out.println("Numero identificativo de persona "+(i+1)+": "+arregloDenumeroIdentificativos[i]);
}

}
```

Comment: Gracias Dramaturgo. Tengo una duda más. Si quisiese limitar la entrada de datos del número identificativo, y que sólo se puedan introducir valores entre 0 y 100, ¿cómo podría hacerlo? Gracias

Comment: habria que colocar una condicional que te lanze un mensaje de aviso y termine el programa si el usuario ingresase un numero menor igual a 0 o mayor igual a 100 ,modifique la respuesta .saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha quedado claro. Saludos